# Bootstrap: автоматическое закрытие окна

Tags: jquery, php, bootstrap

Делаю регистрацию и отправляю данные через `AJAX` запрос обработчику `reg.php` (без перезагрузки страницы), в нем обычная регистрация и т.д но, после регистрации нужно что бы окно это, допустим, через определенное количество секунд исчезало, как это сделать в самом обработчике?  `reg.php`.

Comment: php код не поможет. Вам нужен обычный javascript. используйте функцию [setTimeout](http://javascript.ru/setTimeout) и [window.close](http://javascript.ru/window.close).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

лично я не совсем понял, о каком окне идет речь - либо это какое-то модальное окно с оверлеем (ну или без него, не суть), или это отдельное окно вызываемое через js?
В первом варианте необходимо в случае успешного ответа от сервера хайдить блок (display: none; или visible: none;), в случае ошибки обрабатывать и показывать их пользователю
вот самый простой пример

http://js.do/sonrac/test_modal
я не думал о красоте кода в нем, поэтому не нужно принимать как за идеал, это один из возможных вариантов

Во втором варианте при открытии окна сохранять ссылку на него, и потом вызывать handlerWindow.close(), где handlerWinow собственно указатель на открытое окно, правда помните, что такой способ скорее всего не будет работать на iOS, так как указатель теряется, во всяком случае у меня не получилось это поправить.